# Do you have to define the environment of a function in R?

Tags: r, function, scope, environment

Do you have to explicitly define the environment of a custom function in R, or is it automatically "created" (defined?) when a function is created?

I want to know if creating a function automatically creates an environment within said function or whether the environment needs to be explicitly created. If the former is true (i.e., the environment is automatically created), how do I explicitly refer to it?

Must I first create a new environment for said function (i.e., by assigning a new environment using `new.env`) or can I simply use some other syntax (perhaps something like "`current.env()`")?

The only simple example I can come up with that would use this is `assign` functions inside the function.

```
function(a,b) {
  assign(paste(a,b,sep='.'), 'help me', envir = ONLY CURRENT FUNCTION)
}
```

Comment: I suspect a small code example could help illustrate what you are trying to do here - could you?

Comment: You can use the `get()` function; the first argument is the string name of the variable and the named 'envir' argument is the env you want to query.... `get('a', envir=my.env)`

Comment: I think if you don't worry about it, things will work just fine. `for` doesn't have it's own environment or scope.

Comment: @BadZen ok. But how do I select the environment of the function I'm working in as `my.env`? In other words how do I reference the environment of the function that `get` is in?

Comment: Why do you want to select the environment of the function you are in? You're already in it. You'll just get things by name. Please try and add a code example to your question to show what the problem is.

Comment: `environment()` returns the lexically-current env

Comment: @Spacedman - In R, environments/lexical scopes are first-class objects.  You can pass them around like Javascript contexts and do awful call-by-name stuff.  It's a whole thing. =)

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using assign at all.

Comment: You should provide a minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that makes it clear what problem you are trying to solve. It sounds like there are probably better ways to write your R code then the way you are pursuing.

Comment: @MrFlick I don't know how to do it, which is why I can only provide a non-working example to illustrate my question.

Comment: @theforestecologist Well, you should have some idea of what you want your input and output to be. Why do you think you need references to particular scopes? What code did you try that didn't work, and how are you hoping that it would work. Also, don't change your question to ask new questions. Start a new post if you have a different issue. But i'm worried you are simply headed down the wrong path.

Comment: Fine Fine...Let me start over. I just want to know if creating a function automatically creates an environment within said function or whether the environment needs to be explicitly created. If the former is true (i.e., if the environment is automatically created), how do I *explicitly* refer to it?

Comment: A function doesn't create an environment when it's defined (but it is defined in the context of an environment). A new environment is created with the function runs. And that can be returned with `environment()` from within the function. Buy why do you think you need that? It still isn't clear.

Comment: All user-defined functions are closures. There is always an environment associated with them.

Comment: @MrFlick. I need it for two reasons. The first, is to just simply try to understand how it works. The second, is to expand that new understanding to applying further applications of scope. The second question I asked in this question (which I've since deleted) is how do I refer to the current *within*-function environment *concurrently* with the function's parent environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current environment is returned by `environment()`:

```
> environment()
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
> foo <- function() environment()
> foo()
<environment: 0x1391b88>
> foo()
<environment: 0x1391f08>
> foo()
<environment: 0x1392288>
> foo()
<environment: 0x13916a0>
```

Notice that each call to `foo()` has a different environment as the environment you are thinking about only gets created when the function is called.

To get the enclosing frame, where the function was called from, use `parent.frame()`:

```
> bar <- function() parent.frame()
> bar()
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

As `bar()` was called from my workspace, the global environment is returned. But, if we call `bar()` from inside another function, we get the environment of *that* function as that is now the calling environment:

```
> foobar <- function() { print(environment()); bar() }
> foobar()
<environment: 0x74a7d68>
<environment: 0x74a7d68>
```

If we look at your `assign()` example, you don't have to tell it which environment to use if you want the current environment as that is how it is setup to work by default. But, if you wanted to be explicit about this you'd use:

```
foo <- function(x) {
  assign("y", x, envir = environment())
  y # return(y) to show it is assigned `x`
}
```

Which gives

```
> foo(20)
[1] 20
> foo(10)
[1] 10
> foo("a")
[1] "a"
```

If you want to assign in the parent frame, just pass `envir = parent.frame()`:

```
foo <- function(x) {
  assign("y", x, envir = parent.frame())
  "not returning `y`" # return something else
}
```

which gives

```
> ls()
[1] "bar"    "foo"    "foobar"
> foo(20)
[1] "not returning `y`"
> ls()
[1] "bar"    "foo"    "foobar" "y"     
> y
[1] 20
```

Even though we didn't return `y`, the `assign()` created `y` in the environment we specified.

It is important to stress though that rarely should one be doing `assign()` like this, to assign into other environments. A major reason for this is that now your function has side effects and R is a functional language where it is easier to reason about how code works by having a function take inputs and return outputs, without affecting anything else. Hence you would prefer

```
foo1 <- function(x) {
  y <- x
  y
}

y <- foo1(x)
```

over

```
foo2 <- function(x, varname) {
  assign(varname, x, envir = parent.frame())
  invisible()
}

foo2(x, "y")
```

because I know that calling `foo1()` has no side effects, it's just taking some inputs and returning an output. This is a little contrived because you chose `assign()` but this would apply broadly. It's also the reason why complex lists or other types of objects are returned from many R functions, especially those fitting a model.

Comment: THANK YOU. This is the exact *simple* explanation I was looking for. This thoroughly answers all of my questions.

Comment: @theforestecologist You could do a lot worse than read Hadley Wickham's account of Environments from his Advanced R book, which has a free-to-read web version: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Also, could you help me out with an extension of this question (see chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132428/room-for-theforestecologist-and-gavin-simpson)

Answer (score 0):

Don't mention an environment in the assign.

```
 foo = function(a,b){
  assign(paste(a,b,sep="."),99)
 return(hey.you) # note this is hard coded here...
}
```

There's nothing called `hey.you`:

```
> ls()
[1] "foo"
```

I call `foo`, which creates a `hey.you` and returns its value:

```
> foo("hey","you")
[1] 99
```

But doesn't mess up my environment because it was created in the function's environment:

```
> ls()
[1] "foo"
```

because that's the default.

```
?assign

    pos: where to do the assignment.  By default, assigns into the
          current environment.  See ‘Details’ for other possibilities.
```

If you HAD to mention it explicitly, and you don't have to, so don't, unless you can give us a **real good** reason why you have to, then just copy what assign does:

```
> foo = function(a,b){assign(paste(a,b,sep="."),99,envir=as.environment(-1));ls()}
> foo("fnord","fnord")
[1] "a"           "b"           "fnord.fnord"
```

Or copy what everyone else has been saying here:

```
> foo = function(a,b){assign(paste(a,b,sep="."),99,envir=environment());ls()}
> foo("bubble","gum")
[1] "a"          "b"          "bubble.gum"
```

Comment: but if I HAD to reference the current environment of the function, how would I do that?

Comment: Why isn't `environment()` doing what you want?

Comment: Just copy what assign does: `assign(paste(a,b,sep="."),99,envir=as.environment(-1))`

Comment: @BadZen I don't fully understand how to use `environment()`. Would I just use `assign(paste(a,b,sep='.'), envir = environment())`?

Comment: @theforestecologist for your purposes, you just use `environment()` like that, without any arguments. `environment()` does have 1 argument, `fun` which defaults to `NULL`, which allows other behaviour, such as to look up the environment of the function, it's closure - try `environment(lm)` for example - but you don't need that for the cases you cover in the question.

Comment: @theforestecologist you keep forgetting to put a `value` in your example assign functions.

Comment: oops. you're right. sorry I was distracted by the environment part that I kept forgetting since it's trivial to the question I'm asking... :p